# passing parameter optimization in java

Tags: java, optimization, parameter-passing

does it matter in java which parameters I pass to a method? For example, I have some methods for validation. Let's say I have a class `Person` holding personal information and one method in another class validating e-mail addressees. In my `Controller` class, where I use the `Person` and the `Validator` classes, should I pass the whole `person` object, or should I pass just the String with the email `person.getEmail()`. In the first option, the `Person.validateEmail(Person person)` method can call `person.getEmail()`. So, does it matter how 'big' the passed parameter is? I mean in terms of memory/cpu.

Comment: You are passing copies of references. The type of the referenced object doesn't matter.

Comment: Besides the answers already given I'd encourage you to pass the `Person` object iff the validation takes into account more information from that person than just the email address. This allows for more type safety. OTOH, if you only want to verify the mail address, do NOT pass the person object, this would render your verify-method not reusable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter, since all you are passing is a reference to the object in question. See [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference/40523) for the details.

The one exception is when the method call is remote, then the entire object graph has to be serialized. The time this takes depends on the number of fields and amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

In `java` when you pass whole object of `Person`, you just pass an address of that object. So, doing that you are not coping entire object, only its reference.

In that case it doesn't matter in terms of performance what yo will pass: single email address or `person` object, which contains that email.

On the other hand it depends on how you will use that method in future. If this method is some kind of `utility` method, which does something with an abstract email, so it will be good interface solution to pass in it only `String` parameter with e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Java pass parameter as call by value , not call by reference.  So In case of object its pass only address value of person class.